# Non-templated container that can hold anything

Tags: c++, stl

I have a small framework for working with threads. The main part is an object that is basically a mutex controlled `std::queue` that one thread pushes onto, and the other thread pops from.

This class cannot be templated, because the types of objects can vary in a single run. Currently, I created a dumb class:

```
class Object {
public:
    Object(){}
    virtual ~Object(){}
};
```

Any object that is to flow from thread to thread via this class must inherit from `Object` as it is what the `std::queue` holds. This works well, but I imagine there must be a better approach as this approach requires inheritance and many calls to `dynamic_cast`. Any ideas?

**EDIT** The pointers in this case are also smart pointers, so type information is important to be maintained.

Comment: If there are not too much different types passed then why not using a dedicated queue for each?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use std::queue<[boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/any.html)>. It will hold objects of any type.

And to get the object, you've to use a special cast function provided by boost itself:

- [boost::any_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost/any_cast.html)

Comment: Interesting. Is `dynamic_cast` still required to get any `any` to a specific object type?

Comment: @steveo: no, you use `any_cast` for that, which is implemented in terms of `typeid`.

Comment: @steveo: No. Its `any_cast`. See my answer again.

Comment: Off the top of your head, is `any_cast` better or worse than a `dynamic_cast` with regards to performance? Or shall I start Googling?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `void*` in your container for a "pointer to unknown type" (or `const void*` if the objects are immutable).  It still requires casting (and therefore type information from some other side channel), but you really don't have any other options if you want to avoid templates and inheritance.

Comment: This has the obvious limitation of being totally unsafe.  `boost::any` solves this problem more elegantly.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/any.html) if you want to be more typesafe.

Answer (score 1):

The question is how the types can vary.  You certainly have to have some
constraints on what goes into the container.  Why are the objects put
into the container?  Based on this, you should be able to design are
reasonable abstract base class which would allow virtual functions to be
used for the dispatching, rather than deriving from an artificial
`Object` with no interface.  (Depending on the purpose of the container
is, some variant of the visitor pattern may be necessary.  Thus, for
example, a message queue might contain a virtual function
`processMessage( Base* )`, whose concrete implementations do nothing but
call different member functions of `Base`.)

Comment: They actually can be anything. Think of the situation of distributed processing. One message may be a `vector<char>` that contains raw processed data, another may be a struct that contains updated information about the data, like a header, while another may be a shutdown message. They can be anything.

Comment: @steveo: no exactly. Probably you can use `std::queue<std::function<void()>>` for a better design. Just `pop` a message and call it.

Comment: @steveo225 That's not "anything" The objects have to be messages, which can be processed at the other end.  ybungalobill has described more or less what I was thinking of when I proposed a variant of the visitor pattern.

Comment: No, it can be anything. I just gave a minimal example. It is a framework, so however the user wishes to use it. I have seen sockets and file pointers, strings, callback functions, raw data, streams, things that get executed and things that do not be sent. And I don't want to start making limitations now. I want to remove the inheritance requirement, so when it is a callback for example, the user doesn't have to make a class just to run a function, they can simply provide the pointer to the function.

Comment: @steveo225 In that case, there's always `boost::any`.  But in any particular use, it can't be anything: sender and receiver have to agree as to what it can be.  So I'd probably make it a template, which enforces such invariants over the type system at compile time.